# Работа с regexp в Yandex Metrica API

Tags: python, yandex-metrika-api

Обращаюсь к API Yandex Metrika для того, чтобы программно получить статистику посещений определённых страниц. В интерфейсе метрики можно фильтровать посещения определённой страницы, если в адресе в любом месте есть подстрока. Пример фильтра: @77800006

Также можно использовать и регэксп, чтобы фильтровались только посещения страниц, где подстрока имеет однократное вхождение в конце адреса. Пример фильтра: ~ *77800006$

Если пытаюсь сделать тоже самое через код, то возникает ошибка.

```py
import requests
import sys

page_id='77800006'
header = {'Authorization': 'OAuth [token]'}
payload = {
    'metrics': 'ym:s:visits,ym:s:users,ym:s:pageviews',
    'date1':'2023-10-10',
    'date2':'2023-10-12',
    'ids': COUNTER_ID,
    'dimensions':'ym:s:date',
    #'filters':f'ym:pv:URL=~ *{page_id}$',
    'filters':f'ym:pv:URL=@{page_id}',
    'sort':'ym:s:date',
    'lang':'en',
}

r = requests.get('https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data', params=payload, headers=header)
print(r.json()['data'])
```

Выполнение кода вернёт

```
[{'dimensions': [{'name': '2023-10-10'}], 'metrics': [18.0, 17.0, 380.0]},
 {'dimensions': [{'name': '2023-10-11'}], 'metrics': [24.0, 23.0, 532.0]},
 {'dimensions': [{'name': '2023-10-12'}], 'metrics': [24.0, 21.0, 479.0]}]
```

А если в параметре передать `'filters':f'ym:pv:URL=~ *{page_id}$`, то вернётся ошибка

> {'errors': [{'error_type': 'invalid_parameter', 'message': 'Incorrectly specified filter for segmentation, value: ym:pv:URL=~ *77800006$, error code: 4003'}], 'code': 400, 'message': 'Incorrectly specified filter for segmentation, value: ym:pv:URL=~ *77800006$, error code: 4003'}